# FOSUserBundle logout with prefix doesn't work

Tags: symfony, localization, fosuserbundle

I am having a very strange problem with symfony2 and the FOSUserBundle.

I can logout with /en/logout, but not with /nl/logout or /fr/logout.

When I try to logout with nl or fr I get:

```
You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration.
```

Although I configured it. I can't seem to wrap my head why the /en/logout works and the rest doesn't.

This is my code:

### security.yml

```
security:
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            default_target_path: /%locale%/login
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            failure_path:   /%locale%/login
        logout:
            path: /%locale%/logout
            target: homepage
        anonymous:    true
```

### routing.yml

```
user bundle > FOS
    fos_user_security:
        resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
        prefix: /{_locale}
        requirements:
            _locale: fr|nl|en
```

### controller

```
    class LoginController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("{_locale}/logout-test", name="logout", defaults={"_locale"="en"} , requirements = {"_locale" = "fr|en|nl"})
     * @Template()
     */
    public function logoutAction()
    {
        $test = "";
        #throw new \RuntimeException('You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration.');
        #return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage'));;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out, or tell me where to look next? It would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to define default_target_path as /login , with no locale?

Comment: the login works fine, its the logout that is causing trouble

Comment: Try to define logout as path: /logout$

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In your configuration file, you need to use routes instead of URLs. If it starts with a "/" it will be treated as an URL, else it will be treated as a route. If you use routes instead of URLs, the locale will be taken care of automatically. For example, here is my security.yml configuration:

```
security:
  public:
    pattern:   ^/
    form_login:
      login_path: fos_user_security_login
      check_path: fos_user_security_check
      provider: fos_userbundle
      csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
      default_target_path: index
    anonymous: true
    logout:
      path: fos_user_security_logout
      target: index
```

Answer (score 0):

I leave this for future reference, in addition to @jfcartier's answer:

In case you need a custom `logout` path instead of `fos_user_security_logout`:

```
# app/config/security.yml
...
  logout:
     path: my_logout
     target: homepage
```

... then you also need to define it in `routing.yml`:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

my_logout:
    path: /logout

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

Though, make sure that it's defined before `fos_user` - otherwise you'll get the same error: *You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration.*