# FOSUserBundle - You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration

Tags: symfony, security, fosuserbundle, firewall, logout

I am using Symfony 2.8.2 with FOSUserBundle. When I'm trying to logout, I got the following error:

> You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration

Here's my security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/login
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            anonymous: true
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /login

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

I've also tried to set **logout: true** but nothing changed.

P.S. I'm not using Sonata, just FOSUserBundle.

What's the reason I'm getting this error?

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941989/fosuserbundle-logout-with-prefix-doesnt-work

Comment: Not really, that solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have wrong pattern for `main` firewall.

Setting `pattern: ^/login` makes this firewall valid only for matching URLs which is only `/login` URL.

Also, logout URL has to be inside firewall's secured area.

Answer (score 1):

you must add in your **security.yml**

```html
firewalls:
       secured_area:   
              logout:
                  path:   /logout
                  target: /
```

and in your routing.yml

```html
logout:
    path: /logout
```