# Force /logout does not work (acces_denied_url:)

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

So I made that Role_User could access the website only from a certain IP adress. Everything works like a charm except if a user is connecting from a different IP I try to redirecting it to /en/logout. But it pops up an error
"You must activate the logout security firewall configuration".
Really need help.

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User: bcrypt

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
            anonymous: true
            stateless: false

            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\TokenAuthenticator

            remember_me:
                secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800
                path:     /

            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:
                path: fos_user_security_logout
                target: /(%app_locales%)/login
            access_denied_url: /(%app_locales%)/logout
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:        ROLE_USER
        ROLE_TEAMLEAD:    ROLE_CUSTOMER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_TEAMLEAD
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    access_control:
        - { path: '^/(%app_locales%)/timesheet', role: ROLE_USER, ip: [IP.IP.IP.IP] }
        - { path: '^/(%app_locales%)/timesheet', role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: '^/(%app_locales%)/timesheet', roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
        - { path: '^/(%app_locales%)$', role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: '^/(%app_locales%)/login', role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: '^/(%app_locales%)/register', role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: [IP.IP.IP.IP] }
        - { path: '^/(%app_locales%)/resetting', role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: [IP.IP.IP.IP] }
        - { path: '^/(%app_locales%)/', roles: ROLE_USER, ip: [IP.IP.IP.IP] }
        - { path: '^/api', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED, ip: [IP.IP.IP.IP] }
        - { path: '^/(%app_locales%)/login$', roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide path to logout in your `access_control` list with right parameters. Now your `/en/logout` authorised by role `ROLE_USER` and ip `[IP.IP.IP.IP]`. You need to add next line:

```
access_control:
    ...
    - { path: '^/(%app_locales%)/logout', roles: ROLE_USER }
    ...
```

As you can see I removed dependency on IP-address to be authorised on path `/en/logout`. Now it depends only on `ROLE_USER` role of your user.

Comment: Does your user have role `ROLE_USER`? Try with `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` role. Also check to have line from answer before your line `- { path: '^/(%app_locales%)/', roles: ROLE_USER, ip: [IP.IP.IP.IP] }`. And don't forget about cache clearing ;-)

Comment: yes in dev menu it still shows connected user as authenticated by 'Token class UsernamePasswordToken" Your answer line is on the top of my access_control list. I tried moving it in various places but unfortunately it still the same

Answer (score 0):

I think that on top of the `access_control` entry that Michael posted, you should change the

```
access_denied_url: /(%app_locales%)/logout
```

into

```
access_denied_url: fos_user_security_logout
```

That seemed to be the issue in a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941989/fosuserbundle-logout-with-prefix-doesnt-work)